# XPath: Retrieving text from a class

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, xpath-2.0, lxml.html

Given the following HTML string, parsed by lxml:

```
<strong class="footer"> 
  <span class="icon-new"><i class="icon-new"/></span> 
  16 
</strong>
```

How can I extract the number **16** with XPath?

Comment: maybe the title of this question isn't perfect.

Comment: Then edit it! That's what the edit button is for.

Answer (score 2):

as '16' text is under the `strong` tag, you may do it like:

```
>>> root = etree.fromstring(html)
>>> root.xpath('//strong[@class="footer"]/text()[normalize-space()]')[0].strip()
'16'
```

Answer (score 1):

with pure Xpath

```
//strong[@class='footer']/normalize-space(text()[position()=last()])
```

Comment: this returns `XPathEvalError: Invalid expression`